# Tizen: GBS --deps option not working

Tags: tizen

I was going though the GBS build options and came accross "--deps"
which says when used will build the package as well the packages it
depends on. I tried to build (locally without internet connection)
sample project like cairo under framework/grqaphics. Used the below
command,

gbs build -A armv71 -R localRepo --binary-list=cairo --deps

My expectation was, the above command will build all the packages that
cairo depends on and then will build cairo. But, the build failed
showing nothing provides error.

Does the --deps really works as mentioned? I am doubtful. Wanted to
try --rdeps option but as --deps itself didn't work as expected, have
left it.

Any inputs or pointers in this regard is really appreciated.

Comment: But do you have all dependencies source code with .spec files in git repository?